# Python -- mismatch of columns between training data and prediction data

Tags: python, scikit-learn

in my model I have figured out i made a mistake by not dropping a column from prediction dataset.

This column; yclass; is not available in training dataset. But in my prediction dataset it is available.

I wasn't aware of that mistake, but now I am confused? Why it is still giving me predictions with that abundant column? Shouldn't it give me some kind of error because of that? I have seen the examples of onehotencoding related training-test data inconsistency and solution to that problem. But it is a new case which I do not have an idea? Here is the final part of my code; may be I am making a mistake with pipelines etc.

```
    lgbr = LGBMRegressor(learning_rate= 0.1, max_depth= 18, n_estimators= 50, num_leaves= 11)
    lgbc = LGBMClassifier(learning_rate = 0.1, max_depth = 18, n_estimators = 100, num_leaves = 51)

    numeric_pipe = make_pipeline(MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (-1,1)))
    categoric_pipe = make_pipeline(OneHotEncoder(sparse = False, handle_unknown='ignore'))
    preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [('num',numeric_pipe, num_cols), ('cat',categoric_pipe,cat_cols)])

    regr_pipe_final = make_pipeline(preprocessor, lgbr)
    regr_pipe_final.fit(df_x_regr, df_y_regr.values.ravel())

    class_pipe_final = make_pipeline(preprocessor, lgbc)
    class_pipe_final.fit(df_x, df_y_class.values.ravel())

    pred_final = pd.DataFrame()

    for key in list(mi.unique_everseen(pred_set['from'] + pred_set['to'])):

        pred_val_list = []

        pred_subset = pred_set[(pred_set['from'] + pred_set['to']) == key]

        lag = 0            

        for i in range(0,predmonths):

            pred = pred_subset.iloc[[i],:]

            class_val = class_pipe_final.predict(pred)

            regr_val = regr_pipe_final.predict(pred)
```

I am making rowwise predictions to generate a moving forecast effect, thats why I use for loops for predictions.

Here, as a final summary, the problem is "pred" has 1 abundant column inside, named as "yclass". How is my pipeline accepting that column as an input? Or just ignoring it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly and your code, assuming yclass is one of the One-Hot columns, you have a parameter there:

```
handle_unknown='ignore'
```

Which tells the encoder to ignore column it has not seen in data.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

handle_unknown : ‘error’ or ‘ignore’, default=’error’.
Whether to raise an error or ignore if an unknown categorical feature is present during transform (default is to raise). When this parameter is set to ‘ignore’ and an unknown category is encountered during transform, the resulting one-hot encoded columns for this feature will be all zeros. In the inverse transform, an unknown category will be denoted as None.

Comment: I can understand your comments. I suspected from that issue but in training set there is not anything related to yclass. If it was there and it was onehotencoded, columns would be yclass_0 and yclass_1(which is an abundant operation of course, it is an already binary variable).  Furthermore, if my prediction set had a third category, called yclass_2, it would ignore that. 

But here it is not related to a new category for an already existing variable. It is totally a new variable which was not available while I was fitting the model.